# Android IME, how to retrieve the values from it?

Tags: java, android, ime

I would like to retrieve values (keys) from the IME of android, though I'm unable to find the starting point, how to connect it with my application.

I'm building a custom view. Therefore any recommendations concerning TextView, EditView won't help. Any ideas how to do it? for example just outputting it to LogCat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find any solution that would work directly with Android's IME. So I've made a little trick by subclassing an `EditText` that implements `TextWatcher`. If require to input some data I use `addContentView` (specifying layer parameters of 1x1 px) together with `requestFocus` on the `EditText` class and it calls for the IME for me that shoots values via the `TextWatcher` interface.

Hope this is going to help people who had stumbled upon this uneasy task.